# Basis for a kernel and the image for a linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Can someone verify if what I did is right for the following question? I think I got it right but I'm not sure if my understanding is correct.

> Consider the linear transformation $$\varphi:\mathcal{P}_3 \to \mathbb{R}^3$$ $$p \mapsto \begin{pmatrix} p(0)-p(1)+p(2)\\
> p(0)+p(1)+p(2)\\
> p(0)+p(2) \end{pmatrix}$$ which has matrix:
> $$[\varphi]_{\mathcal{E}\leftarrow\mathcal{B}}\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 & 3 & 7 \\
> 3 & 3 & 5 & 9\\
> 2 & 2 & 4 & 8\end{pmatrix}$$
> with respect to the basis $\mathcal{B}=\{1,x,x^2,x^3\}$ of $\mathcal{P}_3$ and the standard basis $\mathcal{E}$ of $\mathbb{R}^3$.

> a) Find a basis for $Ker(\varphi)$.

> b) Find a basis for $Image(\varphi)$.

My attempt:

$$[\varphi]_{\mathcal{E}\leftarrow\mathcal{B}}=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 & 3 & 7 \\
3 & 3 & 5 & 9\\
2 & 2 & 4 & 8\end{pmatrix} \to \begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 & 0 & -2 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 3\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$$

This implies $x_1+s-2t=0$,$x_3+3t=0$,$x_2=s$ and $x_4=t$ for free variables $s$ (for the 2nd column) and $t$ (for the fourth column).

This implies $x=s\begin{pmatrix}-1\\
1\\
0\\
0\\
\end{pmatrix}+t\begin{pmatrix}2\\
0\\
-3\\
1\\
\end{pmatrix}$

a) A basis for Ker$(\varphi)=\left\{ \begin{pmatrix}-1\\
1\\
0\\
0\\
\end{pmatrix} ,\begin{pmatrix}2\\
0\\
-3\\
1\\
\end{pmatrix}\right\}$

b) A basis for Im$(\varphi)$= $\{1+3x+2x^2,3+5x+4x^2\}$

Is my approach correct? I'm not sure about this. Thanks!

Comment: The image of $\varphi$ should be a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$, then its bases can never have elements from $\mathcal{P}_3$. On the other hand, the kernel of $\varphi$ is a subspace of $\mathcal{P}_3$.

Comment: Yes I got it now thank you :) . I realized I mixed them both up.